# How to show time in my text box also current month date i can't able to select

Tags: magento-1.9, datepicker

In backend i added date and time

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
    Calendar.setup({
    inputField : 'shipping_pickup_at_store_date',
    ifFormat : '%d-%m-%Y',
    showsTime: false,
    button : 'shipping_pickup_at_store_date',
    singleClick : true,
    disableFunc: function(date) {
    //disable previous day in datepicker
        var now= new Date();
        if(date.getFullYear()<now.getFullYear())
        {
            return true;
        }
        if(date.getFullYear()==now.getFullYear())
        {
            if(date.getMonth()<now.getMonth())
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        if(date.getMonth()==now.getMonth())
            {
            if(date.getDate()<now.getDate())
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    },
    });
    // ]]>
</script>
```

in DataPicker it shows date and time if i select in my textbox it will show only data how i show time

**Also I can't able to choose current month date**

Comment: Did you get solution for your problem? @kothari

Answer (score 0):

Use only below code, It will add time and allow to select dates from current month.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
    Calendar.setup({
    inputField : 'shipping_pickup_at_store_date',
    ifFormat : '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M',
    showsTime: true,
    button : 'shipping_pickup_at_store_date',
    singleClick : true,
    });
    // ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: it's come like this 19-05-2017 %h:05

Comment: i can't able to select current month

Comment: Please check updated code